# Error in PHP CodeIgniter 3 when generating pre-signed URLs for multiple S3 objects

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, codeigniter-3

I am encountering an issue in my PHP CodeIgniter 3 application while attempting to generate pre-signed URLs for multiple S3 objects from an Amazon S3 bucket. The process works well when I fetch a single object, but I encounter a "Fail to load response data" error when using a loop to iterate through a list of objects.

My code that i am trying

```
public function getAllCoursesList() {
         error_reporting(E_ALL);
         ini_set('display_errors', '1');
         ini_set('memory_limit', '9000M');
         ini_set('max_execution_time', '900');
         extract($_POST);
         if (!empty($_POST) && $_POST != NULL) {
             if (!isset($search)) {
                 $search = '';
             }
             $this->config->load('aws');
             $bucket = __AWS_BUCKET;
             $s3Client = new S3Client([
                 'version' => 'latest',
                 'region' => $this->config->item('aws_region'),
                 'credentials' => [
                     'key' => $this->config->item('aws_access_key'),
                     'secret' => $this->config->item('aws_secret_key')
                 ]
             ]);
             $courseDetails = $this->ProcessingModel->getAllCoursesListDB($userID, $category, $search);
             foreach ($courseDetails as $key => $value) {
                 if ($value->visibility == 1 && $value->assigned == '') {
                     unset($courseDetails[$key]);
                 }
                 unset($request);
                 unset($pdURLWS);
                 $value->description = strip_tags($value->description);
                 $pdfUrl = parse_url($value->imageURL);
                 $pdURLWS = ltrim($pdfUrl['path'], '/');

                 if ($pdURLWS != "img/No_Image_Available.jpg") {
                     try {
                         $fileExists = $s3Client->doesObjectExist($bucket, $pdURLWS);

                         if ($fileExists) {

                             $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
                                 'Bucket' => $bucket,
                                 'Key' => $pdURLWS,
                             ]);

                             $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+30 minutes'); // URL expiration time

                             $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

                             $value->imageURL = $presignedUrl;
                         }
                     } catch (AwsException $e) {
                         echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

                         print_r('AWS Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
                         print_r('AWS Exception Code: ' . $e->getAwsErrorCode());
                         print_r('AWS Exception Type: ' . $e->getAwsErrorType());
                         print_r('AWS Exception Response: ' . print_r($e->getResponse(), true));
                         exit;
                     }
                 }
             }

             if (!empty($courseDetails)) {
                 echo $this->makeOutput($courseDetails, 01, __SUCC);
             } else {
                 echo $this->makeOutput(NULL, 01, __SUCC_COU_EMPTY);
             }
         } else {
             echo $this->makeOutput(NULL, 05, __ERROR);
         }
     }
```

Similar code is working just fine in a different function.

I am using PHP 5.6 application with AWS SDK version 2.0, hosted on CentOS 7 with Apache 2 as the web server.